# How do you pass values to an html in Form Wizard?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-formwizard

I have currently have a view where I pass arguments through the return render at the end of the function, like so:

```
return render(request, 'a.html', 
    {'form': form,
    'current_account': current_account,
    'accounts': accounts},
)
```

Due to a change in design, I now have to integrate Form Wizard. How do you pass the above variable 'current_account' and 'accounts' to a specific html through form Wizard in order for the html to render properly. How do I return the variables to a.html?

Here is the Form Wizard function I have modified:

```
class UserAccounts(SessionWizardView):
    form_list = [FormA, FormB]
    ... more code ...


    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        form = super(VerifyUserAccounts, self).get_form(step, data, files)

        # determine the step if not given
        if step is None:
            step = self.steps.current
            accounts = []

            for item in number_of_accounts_wo_at:
                accounts.append(item)

                current_account = accounts[0]
                accounts = accounts[1:]

        return form
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add context use

```
def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
    context = super(UserAccounts, self).get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)
    if self.steps.current == 'my_step_name':
        context.update({'variable key': variable value})
    return context
```

For further reading click [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_context_data)